# Regarding Grid View

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, buttonclick

I have the following code:

```
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);

    dt.Rows[index: id + 1][0] = TextBox1.Text;
    dt.Rows[index: id + 1][1] = TextBox2.Text;
    dt.Rows[index: id + 1][2] = TextBox3.Text;
    dt.Rows[index: id + 1][3] = TextBox4.Text;

    dt.AcceptChanges();
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
    TextBox3.Text = "";
    TextBox4.Text = "";
    BtnCancle.Visible = false;
    BtnSave.Visible = false;
}
```

For some reason when I edit the fourth row the updated changes effect for the second row.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1)How do you initialize Session["id"] 2) You might get errors due to sorting

Answer (score 0):

Set your [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) properly.

Ensure that the key can uniquely identify only one row in the grid.

You are calling `AcceptChanges()`. This causes the data to be finalized. If there are any sorting rules, your data will be reordered. Row 4 may not be in the same position after accepting changes.